# PCI-e X 16 vs x8

Tags: pci-express

I am about to build my own DL workstation with 4 GPUs (GTX 1080 Ti) to test several models in parallel. 
- The mobo I intend to use is the ASUS WS X299 SAGE LGA 2066 (7 PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (single x16 or dual x16/x16 or triple x16/x16/x16 or quad x16/x16/x16/x16 or seven x16/x8/x8/x8/x8/x8/x8)
- CPU: Intel Core i9-7900X (Max 44 PCI=e lanes)

With these 2 components of the machine what would be the impact on the GPUs performance on a x8,x8,x8,x8 vs x16, x16,x8,x8 PCI-e configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: The number of channels affects the transfer rate to and from graphics memory, not the performance of the GPU itself.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Exactly. That is also why crypto-miner motherboards only use 1 PCIe lane for each GPU card. Only the raw horse-power of the card is needed. The amount of data going between motherboard and GPU is minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In synthetic benchmarks you will see on pure RAM throughput testing that the 8x PCIe lanes slots are slightly slower obviously. (It doesn't make any difference for the computational performance of the GPU's.)

In practice the difference would probably not be noticeable, unless you have a very unusual use-case that requires saturating the throughput to the GPUs often. (Something that involves moving large data-sets continuously between main RAM and a GPU or between 2 GPU cards.)